# NSUTF8StringEncoding or stringWithUTF8String

Tags: iphone, ios, utf-8, xcode4.2

I am having some issues in dealing with characters in NSStrings.

I read a XML file converted to NSData, it is okay, but when I transfer the "Element name" it has not converted to UTF-8.

I've tried here are some examples of the site, but with no success.

My Code is -

```
NSString * S = [NSString stringWithFormat: @ "%@", D];
S = [S stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: I don't understand what he is trying to do or achieve. Doesn't make any sense

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
 NSString *url = S;
 NSString *check=[url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
 check=[check stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%0A" withString:@""];
```

Comment: I tried your tip, but the string continues with the characters and appeared more
Any algorithm that I can check the character in each string and switch to the letter?
look like a character "X" and change to "Y"?

//print to Xcode
Check 1 %0A%20%20%20%20%20%20Intera%5CU00e7%5CU00e3o%20Consultoria%20e%20Assessoria%20S/C%20Ltda%0A